# KineticJs and RGB filter

Tags: image, filter, kineticjs, rgb, hue

Alright so I want to add an rgb slider for images if I could, otherwise I want to make buttons with some different color choices that will change the images hue. I've been trying to work with the kineticjs rgb filter but it doesnt seem to work with mine. Can someone look over my code and see how I can add it to mine. http://jsfiddle.net/dsj00qoy/17/ Also here is kinda a code i made up to try but it wasn't working...

```
document.getElementById('ta3h').addEventListener('click', function () {

     BR.img.filters([Kinetic.Filters.RGB]);
         BR.img.blue(0);
            BR.img.red(100);
          layer.draw(); 
        });
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to cache the image prior to applying a filter:

```
BR.img.cache();

BR.img.filters([Kinetic.Filters.RGB]);
BR.img.blue(0);
BR.img.red(100);

layer.draw();
```

Comment: I tried this but it didn't work, any other ideas or maybe Im putting it in the wrong place or need a different setup than the BR.img?

Comment: I found that adding this works to change the actual image, so maybe theres a work around for the rgb part with this? `document.getElementById('ta3h').addEventListener('click', function () {
 ta3Img.image(images.ta3b) ,


          layer.draw(); 
        });`       Here's my full coding right now, you can find the ta3Img part right near the bottom. Note: this pastebin doesnt include the above part but I tested it and it works when I add the ta3b to Sources at the very bottom. http://pastebin.com/daX3aHmL